# Create a URL to open firefox and then navigate to URL

Tags: firefox, microsoft-edge

I have a website that no longer supports IE11, but users still navigate to this site often with IE11. I know there is a way for 'force' them into Edge if we send them a new link.

```
Microsoft-edge:https://www.website.com/
```

Is there a way that I can also create a link that would so this same thing but open the URL in Firefox?  Something like this:

```
Mozilla-firefox:https://www.website.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

The part before the first colon of a
[URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)
is called "scheme" or it may also be called "protocol".

Creating a new protocol requires administrator permission, since this is
defined in the operating system.
The "Microsoft-edge" protocol is now built into Windows,
so you don't need to create it.

If you are interested in creating a new protocol, perhaps named
"Mozilla-firefox", this requires under Windows a change in the registry.

See the following references:

- [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Launching applications using custom browser protocols](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols)